# show loading gid after press any letter

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I'm trying to show a loading gif after to press some key on a form.

I have this code.
When I press a key the image is shown, but then if you did not press anything, still displays.....
I want something that when I press a key the imagen is display and when I stop to press keys the imagen stop to showing

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>  
</head>
<body>
    Enter your name: <input type="text" id="fname" onkeyup="displayResult()">
    <img src="ajaxload.gif" id="load" style="display: none">
    <script>
        function displayResult()
        {
            $("#load").show();
        }
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('#fname').keydown(function(){$("#load").show();});
$('#fname').keyup(function(){$("#load").hide();});
```

Try to avoid inline event handlers.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/xY9YN/1/) is a fiddle that does what you want. I don't have your image so I used a div instead.